# How to get the timezone from a PostgreSQL timestamp

Tags: postgresql

This is probably a very simple question, but it's hard to Google because it matches too many different questions.

I want to get the timezone (or offset) of timestamps saved in my database.

For example, right now in my database I have

```
     expired_at      
---------------------
 2018-04-28 00:00:00
 2018-03-28 08:00:00
 2018-02-28 05:00:00
```

I want to find all `expired_at` that has the PST offset.

So my pseudo-code would be something like this

`SELECT expired_at FROM table WHERE expired_at IS IN TIMEZONE('PST')`

Can I get some help. Thanks!

PS. Basically I am trying to fix a data integrity issue by finding all UTC timestamp and updating them to be PST. The database is screwed up right now with a mix of many different timezones.

Comment: Side note: all events (including expiration stamps, like what you have here), should be stored "ignorant" about timezones/offsets.  This doesn't really mean "has no timezone" (ie, `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE`), but rather should be a "doesn't care" situation; this is usually done by explicitly storing everything in UTC.  The reasoning has to do with the fact that an event represents an actual, distinct, specific instant in time, and isn't really bound to any calendar.

Comment: Also, even if there was a function that would allow you to go from hours to time zone, it would generate more problems than it would solve:  There are multiple zones with the same offset(s), most of them with different rules.  There's no way to pick.  At GMT-4:00, there's at least four different rule sets, possibly more.  If you're in DST, Pacific Time is only -7:00, too.

Comment: Also note that PST is not a time zone, it's a time offset. For the zone you'd want to use something like `US/Pacific` or `America/Los_Angeles`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[The documentation on Postgres timestamps says](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-datetime.html):

> For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in
>   UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean
>   Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is
>   converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If
>   no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be
>   in the time zone indicated by the system's TimeZone parameter, and is
>   converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.

Contrary to what a reasonable person might expect when reading `timestamp with time zone`, this Postgres datatype doesn't actually store a timezone. Internally, the value is always converted to UTC.

The information about the input timezone is lost when saving the value to the database. As far as I know, there is no way to get the information you seek.

Comment: Yea you're right. I am an idiot. That's the hours, not the timezone. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The data you want does not exist.  Timestamps do not contain time zone data.  Timestamps are always stored in UTC.  The time zone information is used to convert to UTC on the way into the database, and to format UTC into some other format on the way out.  It is not stored, unless you create an additional column to store it in.

Answer (score -1):

It, probably, depends on the version of your SQL and how table was formatted.
Accordingly to
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html
you can extract the timezone using the keyword

```
SELECT EXTRACT(timezone_hour FROM your_timestamp_column)
```

that gives "The hour component of the time zone offset"
(also you may consider "timezone" and "timezone_minute").
There is also option to extract timezone_minute for the half-hour zones

Comment: there is no function `timezone_hour()` in Postgres. And as Postgres doesn't actually store the timezone, there is no way to retrieve that information

Comment: If this did anything, it would also give the wrong answer for half-hour timezones.

Comment: @DanyloZherebetskyy: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=eeedf8491508280faf8f6dd63aea59c7

Comment: @DanyloZherebetskyy sucks for the ~1.5 billion people living in a half-hour time zone then.

Comment: @OrangeDog thank you for the half-hour zone case, there is option for SELECT EXTRACT(timezone_minute FROM current_timestamp);

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name still again click the link to the official documentation; it is just a matter of syntax, see the example with the hour extraction here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d66f79bebebc641eb985c08cb2ead031

Comment: As Postgres does not store a time zone value in a `timestamp with time zone` that only retrieves the time zone hours from the current session time zone: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=710bd56689c7d9c91b1d787ed2d49f3d  It's essentially the same as `show timezone;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name on top of your example, I provided working example that extracts the timezone. Now, you are saying that PostgreSQL does not store time-zone? I seems the question is "Did DB engineers design tables such that they keep time-zone information or ignore it?". PostgreSQL is capable of storing timezone info and retrieving it (at least, in my company the DB engineers store it and we use it   :-)))

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) "*For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in UTC [...]. An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone*"

Comment: Quote from the same manual  "_[...] time with time zone (though it is supported by PostgreSQL for legacy applications and for compliance with the SQL standard)[...]. PostgreSQL allows you to specify time zones in three different forms_". It is hard to overestimate the use of the time-zone in real-world. Imagine, a non-tech person (carpenter or MD) gets his package shipping updates in UTC, or get an analytics report to Board of Directors or Congress in UTC? UTC is for engineering convenience. Moreover, look at the initial question - answer, is provided for time-zone aware PostgreSQL!

Comment: @DanyloZherebetskyy it would appear that neither you nor the db engineers in your company have any idea how postgres works.

Comment: You're both right (and wrong). :) Postgres doesn't store the timezone; it definitely converts incoming timestamps to UTC … *for `timestamp with time zone` columns*. I wouldn't advise using strings, necessarily, *BUT* those `extract` functions definitely exist (read the docs mentioned) … apparently for the case where you're dealing with *strings*.

`SELECT EXTRACT(timezone_hour FROM '2023-01-01 01:00-06'::timestamptz);
SELECT EXTRACT(hour FROM '2023-01-01 01:00-06'::timestamptz);`

Comment: @OrangeDog not a constructive comment, but it would appear that you neither can comprehend the question and answers nor able to read documentation  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#:~:text=PostgreSQL%20assumes%20your%20local%20time,being%20displayed%20to%20the%20client. and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/timezones.html

Comment: @DanyloZherebetskyy the documentation agrees with us. Postgres does not store timezone information in any of its timestamp types.